# Array.map() and D3 selection?

Tags: javascript, svg, selector, d3.js

Is there anything like `Array.map()` for a D3 selection? To find the maximum length of a selection of SVG `<text/>` elements, I currently do the following. However `.selectAll(...)[0].map(...)` seems like a hack to me. Is there a better way?

```
      var chi = svg.selectAll('.chi');

      var xChi = d3.max(chi[0].map(function (itm) { return itm.getComputedTextLength(); }));
```

I can use `selection.each()` to iterate a function over a selection, but I'm not sure how to combine this with `d3.max()`. I tried `d3.max(chi.each(function (itm) { return itm.getComputedTextLength(); }))`, but `d3.each()` doesn't return an array of the return values

Answer (score 2):

```
var allLength

d3.selectAll(".element")
.each(function(d, i) {allLength[i]=d3.select(this).node().getComputedTextLength() })

var maxLength = d3.max(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but so does `d3.max(svg.selectAll('.chi')[0].map(function (itm) { return itm.getComputedTextLength(); }));` It seems like an omission for there not to be an equivalent of `Array.map()` for a D3 selection?

Answer (score 1):

Yea..that bracket makes my eyes sore too.

```
d3.max(svg.selectAll('.chi').pop(), function(item) {
  return itm.getComputedTextLength()
})
```

The question was from 2012. I don't know what d3 was like back then, but the current version has `d3.max` accepts an accessor function to retrieve the value you're max-ing.